# NPE when using PATCH/PUT with @Transient Map

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-rest

I have an entity with:

```
@Transient private Map<String, Object> properties;
```

These properties are mapped in `@PrePersist` and `@PreUpdate` to other fields.

When I exec a POST all is fine, but when I exec a patch or put I get:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BeanWrapper.getProperty(BeanWrapper.java:81)
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.json.DomainObjectReader.doMerge(DomainObjectReader.java:195)
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.json.DomainObjectReader.read(DomainObjectReader.java:87)
```

It looks like that SDR handles only persistent fields while patch/put? 
Is this a bug? I have seen some fixed bugs around Map, patch and NPE in SDR Jira, is this a variation of these bugs?